# How to make a distribution plot of labelled data points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make a distribution plot where instead of bars, it uses data points, with the labels of those data points.

This is how the dataframe I have is like:

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['ad','af','ag','ah','aj','gf','fd','ds']
b = ['3-23', '3-23','2-26','1-24','3-07','3-23','2-26','3-07']
c = ['3-25', '3-25','1-20','1-20','2-07','3-21','2-26','2-08']
dft = pd.DataFrame(b,a).reset_index()
dft['c'] = c
```

And then have seperate plots for b and c (sharing the x axis, with the numbers ordered) where there are the numbers on the x axis, no values on the y axis, but data points with the two letter labels stacked up for each number value. And then a legend where each two letter value corresponds to its full name ad=adio, af=afio and so on (just add 'io' to each two letter value).

Comment: I don't know a pre-existing way to do this, but it sounds like a poor way to display your data

Comment: @Josh Friedlander I am copying what was done elsewhere. But I edited so maybe it makes more sense. Say you have a number of teams (the two letter names) trying out some different methods (the columns), and you want to show the dates (the numbers) each team started using those methods. It was done with basically a histogram, where data points are used instead of bars, with each data point corresponding to a team name, sharing the x axis for dates.